# Get User Details from database in Django

Tags: python, jquery, django

I am working in site which display the details of a contact registered in my app, the error I have is when retrieving the data does not show and cannot find the `Ajax` request, any help would be appreciated
**urls.py**

```py
from django.urls import path
from app_2 import views as app2

urlpatterns = [
    #app_2
    path('user', app2.userPanel),
    path('get_user_info', app2.getUserInfo, name = 'get_user_info'),
]
```

**Script in user.html**

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#users").change(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var username = $(this).val();
    var data = {username};
    $.ajax({
        type : 'GET',
        url :  "{% url 'get_user_inf' %}",
        data : data,
        success : function(response){
            $("#user_info table tbody").html(`<tr>
                <td>${response.user_info.first_name || "-"}</td>
                <td>${response.user_info.last_name || "-"}</td>
                <td>${response.user_info.email || "-"}</td>
                <td>${response.user_info.is_active}</td>
                <td>${response.user_info.joined}</td>
                </tr>`)
        },
        error : function(response){
            console.log(response)
        }
    })
   })
})
</script>
```

Comment: What error do you have?

Comment: What is `getUserInfo` in `app2.views`? You also have a typo in your JS `url` because `get_user_inf != get_user_info`

Answer (score 0):

You should add `Ajax` in your `urlpatterns` to specify what are you requesting:

```py
urlpatterns = [
    #app_2
    path('user', app2.userPanel),
    path('Ajax/get_user_info', app2.getUserInfo, name = 'get_user_info'),
]
```

and also there is an error in your code:

```
type : 'GET',
        url :  "{% url 'get_user_info' %}",
        data : data,
        success : function(response)
```

Comment: `Ajax` isn't in the javascript URL being requested though?

Comment: I know, I think there is mistake in my reply as I should say he must specify the `AJAX` as python doesn't consider by it self